# How to get catalog product data in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog

I use these lines below to get the CMS page data,

```
// Get current cms page from Mage:getSingleton
$cms_id = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
$cms_title = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle();
$cms_content = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getContent();
var_dump($cms_content);
```

What about if I want to get a catalog product data? I want to get the product's name for instance,

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$product_id = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdentifier();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
```

result,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\mywebiste.com\app\design\frontend\mywebsite\default\template\page\html\banner.phtml
>   on line 6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error basically means that the `$product` object is not an object, it is most likely null. I would check what is being returned from `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdentifier();`

If you are on a product page you can use `Mage::registry('product')->getId()` to get the id of  the current product.

Or if you are simply wanting to load an arbitrary product then you can simply specify the id to use.